# Import and export wizard error in sql server 2008r2

Tags: sql-server-2008, import, ssis, data-migration

[image]

I am getting this error when i am trying to import data from tally erp9.0 using import and export wizard in management studio 2008.

Comment: Tt looks like column `DeducteeType` is missing from the destination table `TallyUser`.

Comment: I didn't get you.... what do you mean by DeducteeType

Comment: I think you are trying to import or export database "AlKhalijInternationalLLC". There is a table called "TallyUser" with column "DeducteeType". This column is probably missing from the source or destination location.

Comment: Yeah i am importing data from tally to sql server. DeducteeType is a table name. but i can look at the preview in import and export wizard.

Comment: Maybee "TallyUser" is Tally specific table and you do not need to import it?..

Comment: As of i know "AlKhalijInternationalLLC" is database name, "TallyUser" is Schema name and "DeducteeType" is table name. I can able to look at preview in import and export wizard. But i cannot import data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31665/discussion-between-dips-and-stoleg)